# Разработка под IOS без VM

Tags: windows, ios, xamarin, mobile-development, flutter

Вопрос прост. У меня ОС Виндовс и хочу начать писать под ios используя Xamarin или flutter или что нибудь на подобии. Я вроде прочитал не мало статей про flutter но хотел бы уточнить один вопрос. Возможно ли создать ios app на flutter без macOS на чистом Windows

Comment: @donRumata как ваш комментарий относиться к вопросу? Просто не вижу связи...

Comment: @MiT, а, точно. MacOS же. Прошу прощения.

Answer (score 0):

Нет никакой разницы на какой ОС на данный момент разрабатывается приложение, но без macOS невозможно сделать отладку или сборку приложения. Есть несколько вариантов решить эту проблему:

1. Использовать VM для сборки приложения (медленно, но возможно)
2. Hackintosh для разработки (медленно, больно, возможно)
3. CI/CD для автосборки + авто-тесты ([Codemagic](https://codemagic.io/start/) или [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.com/))

Если вдруг надо будет .travis.yml для flutter:

```
 os: osx 
    language: generic 
    before_script: 
     - brew update 
     - brew install --HEAD usbmuxd 
     - brew unlink usbmuxd 
     - brew link usbmuxd 
     - brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice 
     - brew install ideviceinstaller 
     - brew install ios-deploy 
     - git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b beta --depth 1 
    script: 
     - flutter/bin/flutter build ios --debug --no-codesign
    cache: 
      directories: 
      - $HOME/.pub-cache
    before_deploy: 
      - pushd build/ios/iphoneos 
      - mkdir Payload 
      - cd Payload 
      - ln -s ../Runner.app 
      - cd .. 
      - zip -r app.ipa Payload 
      - popd
```

Хорошая статья по flutter [CI/CD](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667)